# Binomial distribution confidence interval with large measurement error

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, measurement-error

I have an experiment that has two possible outcomes: A and B. The experiment is performed a large number of times and I am trying to find the proportion confidence interval.

The problem, however, is that the measurement is very imprecise and outcome A has a probability p of being measured as outcome B.

Is it possible to find proportion confidence interval in these conditions? If so, then how?

**Edited**

Probability p is known. And B will never be measured as A, only the other way around

Comment: Is $p$ known?  And, is there a probability that B will be measured as A?

Comment: Yes, p is known. And B will never be measured as A, only the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define $a$ as the true probability of $A$, $N_A$ as the observed number of $A$ events, and $N$ as the total number of observations.   We can observe $N_A$ events if there actually are $N_A$ $A$ events and none of them are observed as $B$ events, or $N_A+1$ $A$ events and one of them is observed as a $B$ event, and so forth.  We write the probability distribution as:

$$p(N_A|N,p) = \sum_{i=N_A}^Np_{bin}(i|N, a) p_{bin}(i-N_A|i,p)$$

where $p_{bin}$ is a binomial distribution.

Unfortunately this does not admit of a nice closed-form solution.  Consequently, you will likely have to write some code to solve it.  While we are doing so, we can also construct asymptotic confidence intervals around our point estimate.

An example of such code in R is:

```
a <- 0.5  # Probability of A
p <- 0.2  # Probability of A observed as B
N <- 100  # Sample size

# Randomly generate data
A_act <- rbinom(1, N, a)
A_obs <- rbinom(1, A_act, 1-p) 

# The likelihood function - but we use -2*log likelihood
# because this enables us to use the asymptotic distribution
# of same for constructing confidence intervals in the next step
f <- function(a, N_a, N, p) {
  -2*log(sum(dbinom(N_a:N, N, a) * dbinom(0:(N-N_a), N_a:N, p)))
}

# Calculate MLE
opt <- optimize(f, c(0.01,0.99), N_a=A_obs, N=N, p=p)

# Calculate 95% confidence intervals based on asymptotic chi-square
# distribution of -2 log likelihood using a grid with resolution 0.001 
fval <- 1:999
for (i in 1:length(fval)) fval[i] <- f(i/1000.0, A_obs, N, p)

ci <- c((min(which(fval<opt$objective+qchisq(0.95,1)))-0.001)/1000,
        (max(which(fval<opt$objective+qchisq(0.95,1)))+0.001)/1000)
```

And for our results:

```
> opt
$minimum
[1] 0.4749932

$objective
[1] 5.002835

> ci
[1] 0.360999 0.596001
```

Our point estimate is $0.475$, with an (asymptotic) 95% confidence interval of $(0.361,0.596)$.

Comment: I do not understand the comment about why -2*log is used. The only logic I see is that maybe it can be optimized more efficiently. Is there any other reason?

Comment: Although it is true that the log of the likelihood function is often easier to optimize, the reason for the $-2*$ is because the asymptotic distribution of the likelihood ratio test, which is based on $-2 \log L$, is $\chi^2(n)$, where $n$ parameters are being tested.  Since tests can be converted to confidence intervals and vice versa, using $-2 \log L$ allows us to construct an asymptotic confidence interval for the single parameter $a$ above using the $\chi^2(1)$ distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I have understood the question right...

Let $A_T$ and $B_T$ be the numbers of true events of type A and B respectively. Similarly, let $A_M$ and $B_M$ be the numbers of those events you actually measure. For a very large number of experiments you will get

$A_M=A_T-pA_T$

$B_M=B_T+pA_T$

This is a simultaneous equation with two unknowns, and has solution

$A_T = \dfrac{A_M}{1-p}$

$B_T = \dfrac{p(A_M+B_M)-B_M}{p-1}$

I'm reasonably sure that, if you have confidence intervals on $A_M,B_M$ you can get the confidence intervals on $A_T$, $B_T$ by usual propagation of uncertainties.