# Binomial Test with uncertin data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, uncertainty

I got observational data whether some elements of a population have certain characteristic or not. I want to see if the probability for carrying that characteristic is less than some threshold. This could be easily done with a binomial test to some significance level $\alpha$.
The problem is that the observation has some uncertainty. It happens with some known probability $\gamma$ that the characteristic is not noticed. An error in the other direction does not occur. This means if we observe the characteristic we are sure about that result.
Therefore, the number of elements which do not have that characteristic will be overestimated in my data. My question is how I could incorporate that uncertainty $\gamma$ in my test in such a way that the significance level $\alpha$ is preserved.

I had the following idea but I am not sure if this really works. I want to test if at most 5% of the population carry the characteristic. If the probability of carrying the characteristic is $p$ the probability of the false observation is $p_f$ and the probability of observing the characteristic is $p_c$ we obtain $p = p_c+(1-p_c)p_f$. So I want to test if $p \leq 0.05$. Since we know that $p_f=0.01$ we obtain that $p_c \leq 0.0405$. If I conduct a test with significance level $\alpha$ for the hypothesis $p_c \leq 0.0405$ can I say that with a significance level of $\alpha$ also $p \leq 0.05$? Or is there a different way to test that $p\leq 0.05$?

Comment: Do you have some kind of prior information on the uncertainty $\gamma$, or some possibility of measuring it?

Comment: Yes I can measure it. I can get it down to 1% depending on the quality  of  the observation.

Comment: Please add that new information as an edit to the post, with some new details, how can you measure it, is the probability of error the same in both directions? Not addingbthe info as an edit, very few people will see it ... Some similar posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493668/how-to-model-errors-around-the-estimation-of-proportions-with-measurement-erro, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304168/binomial-distribution-confidence-interval-with-large-measurement-error,